# Matplotlib TwoSlopeNorm use base2 in colorbar

Tags: matplotlib

is there a way to get TwoSlopeNorm in combination with base 2 ticks on the colorbar?

An example is something like this where you have normal linear scaling:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-50,100,1)
y = x.copy()
c = x.copy()
scatter_plot = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='bwr', norm=matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-50, vcenter=0, vmax=100))
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter_plot)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I know based on a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73973227/matplotlib-colorbar-log2) that SymLogNorm supports base2, but it looks like this is not the case for TwoSlopeNorm. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: Why not use a SymLogNorm from -100 to 100?  -100 and -50 will be rather close together.

Comment: I am aware that this would make more sense for this particular example, but I wanted to know if it is possible in general.